# Euler Lagrange Equation and Besse Conjecture

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-functional-analysis

Many paper said that Einstein Hilbert functional $E(g)$ defined as follows $$E(g) = \int_{M} R_{g}dM_{g}$$
If it restricted on unit volume. The Euler Lagrange can be writen as $$Ric - \frac{R}{n} = Hess(f) - (Ric - \frac{R}{n-1}g)f$$
for some function $f$. But how to compute the Euler Lagrange equation for this problem? I have doubt that and the reference always tell us it it easy to see that. But I really do not know. Is there any one know or recommand good references?

Comment: See, e.g., first section of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.599.8478&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Schoen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been discussed in some books and papers. For instance see

- *Schoen, Richard M.*, [**Variational theory for the total scalar curvature functional for Riemannian metrics and related topics**](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.599.8478&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Topics in calculus of variations, Lect. 2nd Sess., Montecatini/Italy 1987, Lect. Notes Math. 1365, 120-154 (1989). [ZBL0702.49038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0702.49038).
- *Barros, Abdênago; Evangelista, Israel*, [**On the critical metrics of the total scalar curvature functional**](http://dx.doi.org/10.5486/PMD.2018.7835), Publ. Math. 92, No. 1-2, 147-158 (2018). [ZBL1399.53078](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1399.53078).
- *Viaclovsky, Jeff A.*, [**Critical metrics for Riemannian curvature functionals**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1405.6080), Bray, Hubert L. (ed.) et al., Geometric analysis. Lecture notes from the graduate minicourse of the 2013 IAS/Park City Mathematics Institute session on geometric analysis, Park City, UT, USA, 2013. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Princeton, NJ: Institute for Advanced Study (IAS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-2313-1/hbk; 978-1-4704-2881-5/ebook). IAS/Park City Mathematics Series 22, 197-274 (2016). [ZBL1360.53005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1360.53005).
- *Besse, Arthur L.*, Einstein manifolds, Classics in Mathematics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-540-74120-6/pbk). xii, 516 p. (2008). [ZBL1147.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1147.53001).